# Injective objects in the category of posets

Tags: category-theory

According to Wikipedia, the injective objects in the category of posets (with monotone maps as arrows) are precisely the complete lattices. I'm a beginner at category theory, so I find myself unable to prove this. I'd be content with a proof that $\omega$ was not injective.

To standardise definitions: $I$ is "injective" iff for all $h: X \to I$ and monic $m: X \to E$, have $h$ lifts over $m$ in the sense that there is a unique $\bar{h}$ such that $\bar{h} \circ m = h$. I am asking about the case $I = \omega$.

I have already proved that the monic arrows in the category of posets are precisely the set-injective monotone functions.

We probably want to use the idea that in $\omega$ we may "shift everything up by one" - using the injective map $n \mapsto n+1$. This ability is what separates the ordinals $\geq \omega$ from the complete ones. Therefore the obvious idea to try is $X = E = \omega$ and $m: \omega \to \omega$ by $n \mapsto n+1$. However, I don't think any $h: X \to I$ fails to lift over this: the map "subtract 1, then do $h$" is monotone whenever $h$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take $E = \omega + 1$ instead, and $X = I = \omega$, then the inclusion $i: X \to I$ by $n \mapsto n$ fails to lift over the inclusion $X \to E$. Indeed, the element $\omega$ has nowhere to go in $I$, since every finite ordinal's image is accounted for already.

Notice that if $I$ were finite, then if we tried this trick we would be able to send the maximum element of $E$ to the maximum element of $I$ without any trouble.